# Verifying the definition of convergence, or showing it does not converge.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Can someone please help me prove whether this sequence converges or not? I am having trouble figuring it out. Should I find some $\epsilon$ such that its greater than our sequence? Thank you for your time and help!

For the following sequence how do I show it converges by guessing the limit? Also, how can I verify  the definition of convergence, or show it does not converge.

(1) Sequence $\{x_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ in $\mathbb{R}$ given by $$x_k = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
         10^{100} & \mbox{if $k =10^{1000}$};\\
        0 & \mbox{if $k\ne 10^{1000}$}.\end{array} \right.$$

$\text{Solution:}$ I believe this converges as $x_k$ goes to 0 but I am not entirely sure.

Comment: If $k > 10^{1000}$ then $x_k = 0$.  so... for any $\epsilon >0$ and $N = 10^{1000}$ the $x > N$ implies $|a_k - 0| = |0-0| =0< \epsilon$ so .... what's the definition of convergence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, yes, the sequence converges (specifically the limit is 0), and you can show this is true by the definition of convergence. If you understand the description of the sequence $(x_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ you have written, you can see that the sequence stays constant at 0 for an extremely long time, then all of a sudden on term $k = 10^{1000}$ it jumps erratically to $10^{100}$, and then the next term immediately goes back to 0, and the sequence stays constant at 0 forever onwards.

The definition of convergence to a the limit $L$ says intuitively that no matter how small the tolerance $\varepsilon$, the difference between your sequence and the limit $L$ will be smaller than this tolerance $\varepsilon$ for all terms beyond some point in the sequence. So here, since the sequence stays constant at 0 for all terms beyond $k = 10^{1000}$, your gut instinct should be that the limit is 0. And you need to ask, is it true that for all terms in the sequence beyond a certain point, will the difference between your sequence and 0 be smaller than any specified $\varepsilon > 0$, as long as you go far enough out on your sequence? And in fact, the answer here is yes, because if you go more than $10^{1000}$ terms in your sequence, your terms will all be exactly 0, and so then the difference between these terms and the limit 0 will also be 0, and so this difference of 0 will of course be smaller than any tolerance $\varepsilon > 0$, because, well, $\varepsilon$ is positive while 0 (being the difference between the limit and your sequence) is smaller than that.

It looks like another answer formalizes this notion of convergence of this sequence to the limit 0.

Comment: Thank you for elucidating this!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the sequence $\{x_k\}$ converges to $0$, because, for any real number $\epsilon>0$,

take $K=10^{1000}+1,$ and then, for all $k\ge K$, $|x_k-0|=0\lt\epsilon$ .

Comment: Thank you for your feedback !